# SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket' when deploying a react.js app in heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, websocket, protocols

I created a simple react.js app (bootstrap with create-react-app) only with chart.js graphs. Everything works fine in local host. Today, I tried to deploy in production via Heroku.

This is the error I'm getting (full version in screenshot) :

> SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

I've seen that it's a common error that may be solved by changing protocol line in react-util-devs : [issue link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079#issuecomment-562373869)

That is to say, in my *node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js* file, I changed line 62 with :

```
protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
```

I tried to deploy again, but keeps having the same error...[image]

Comment: Share here your Websocket connetion code

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue, I think what is happening is that when you do the push to heroku the node_modules are not being updated, you only updated your local version, but this is just what I think... Have someone found a solution for this?

Comment: This medium article solved the issue : https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08; I foolowed every steps and now my app is working in production :D